# How to convert PDF version 1.5 to version 1.4 in PHP

Tags: php, pdf-generation

How to convert PDF version 1.5 to version 1.4 in PHP ? Can anyone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. It may not be possible at all for documents that use specific 1.5 features. What is your situation? Also if this is possible, then only with command line tools. Can you install and call command line tools from PHP on your server?

Comment: What has PHP to do with PDF conversion?

Comment: I am using fpdf and fpdi library to edit my PDFs. The problem is (free version)fpdi and fpdf has limitation that it can process pdf document of version upto 1.4 only. So i wanted to convert any 1.5 document to 1.4 and then process it with fpdi. thanks.

Comment: by the time did you find a way ?

Answer (score 17):

I have a similar requirement, and found that Ghostscript can modify a PDF version. Documentation is here: http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm

However, I didn't find anything specific about the dCompatibilityLevel option in the documentation. Rather, I found this article that demonstrated its use: http://rohieb.wordpress.com/2012/06/09/use-ghostscript-to-convert-pdf-files/

Here is the command:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH 
  -sOutputFile=new-pdf1.5.pdf original.pdf
```

Answer (score 9):

you can easily convert PDF version 1.5 to 1.4 .

you can convert PDF version using 2 ways.

1. use ghostscript command line tool

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE \
  -dBATCH -sOutputFile=new.pdf old.pdf')
```

2. using a PHP library given at github.
   Download it from [here](https://github.com/xthiago/pdf-version-converter)

I developed a PDF encryption tool which encrypt any version of pdf file. I used ghost-script to convert PDF version before passing PDF to fpdi pdf parser for encryption. it is almost done and ready to use . [Here](https://infoconic.com/tools/pdf-file-online-encryption/)

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem for years, without reinstalling any stuff, there is an online converter: https://docupub.com/pdfconvert/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working complete script, not perfect but simple. 
Script reads all pdf's from c:\temp_in\ converts them and saves them as version 1.4 in folder c:\temp_done. Had some trouble with paths to the ghost script so path is declared fully in the shell_exec. Also added some debugging to the script by implementing "2>&1".
(Obviously ghost script is installation is required.)

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir("c:/temp_in/")) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
    if ('.' === $file) continue;
    if ('..' === $file) continue;

    $result = shell_exec('"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.27\bin\gswin64c" -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sOutputFile="c:\temp_done\\'.$file.'" "c:\temp_in\\'.$file.'" 2>&1');
    echo $result;

}
closedir($handle);
}
?>
```